# Add dependency to existing pom.xml via shell

Tags: java, shell, maven-2, dependencies, command-line-interface

Is there a way to add dependencies to an existing pom.xml via shell script?

Something like:

```
mvn dependency:add -DgroupID=com.acme -DartifactId=project
```

[Update]
Clarified that I want to add to an existing pom

Comment: Why would you like to add a dependency via shell script?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm writing a tutorial (non-public) that includes a script that generates a project via archetype generation and adds some dependencies to complete the project. I guess the better way is to create an archetype on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you would like to add that dependency to an existing POM, so the answer is no.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, I meant an existing pom.xml. Would be a nice addition IMO. Too bad. I can understand why though - if you add version numbering or exclusions it becomes a little unwieldy and the logic to inject it maybe to complex.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any plugin doing this (apart from the m2eclipse wizard but that's not what you're asking for). This would be  a nice addition to the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) (in the spirit of [`dependency:get`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html)) though. You should suggest to add the feature: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP (I did a quick search but couldn't find something close).

Comment: @Pascal I opened an issue. Let's wait what the MDEP guys think.